# Related question java vs javascript

Tags: discussion, related-questions

This is a java question: [Implantation Association class in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582522/implantation-association-class-in-java) However all the related questions listed in the page are javascript questions. Is it ever possible to make the related question listing algorithm aware of the fact that **[Java (not to be confused with JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)**?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question was mistagged at first. It's since been tagged correctly, but related questions are cached; expect it to be a little bit before they update.